# preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, swipe, homescreen

in `UIKit` there is an option to disable "Home" system swipe up from bottom (not completely disable, but swipe ignores first time and will force user to repeat it if he really wants it). `setNeedsUpdateOfScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures()` actually does right what I need.

But how do I reach the same in SwiftUI?

I tried to call this method in SceneDelegate like this:

```
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        let uiKitView = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        uiKitView.setNeedsUpdateOfScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures()
        window.rootViewController = uiKitView
```

but its doesn't work if you doesn't override `preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures`to return `.all`
I can't override this computed property of `UIHostingController`:

```
extension UIHostingController {
    open override var preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures: UIRectEdge{
        return [.all];
    }
}
```

I gets warning:

> Extensions of generic classes cannot contain '@objc' members

Anybody knows how to reach that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Update Xcode 14 / iOS 16

Now SwiftUI supports it naturally with `defersSystemGestures` modifier:

```
  body: some View {
    MainView()
      .defersSystemGestures(on: .bottom)   // << here !!
  }
```

#### Original

Just override it in custom hosting controllers

```
class MyHostingController<Content: View>: UIHostingController<Content> {
    open override var preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures: UIRectEdge{
        return [.all];
    }
}
```

and use it as root controller

```
let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)

let controller = MyHostingController(rootView: contentView)
controller.setNeedsUpdateOfScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures()

window.rootViewController = controller
```

Comment: Thanx! It works fine in fullscreen app. Can I reach that in keyboard extension? Posted another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61227987/preferredscreenedgesdeferringsystemgestures-in-keyboard-extension-doesnt-work) about it.