# How can I disable iOS Reachability Swipe Gesture in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swipe, draggesture

I am using the dragGesture in SwiftUI to develop my game. I am facing a problem with iOS Reachability Swipe Gesture. When user tries to swipe down at the very bottom of the device, iOS calls iOS reachability. I need to disable this iOS feature for my app. I checked this link:

[Disable iOS Reachability Swipe Gesture in iOS game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60694506/disable-ios-reachability-swipe-gesture-in-ios-game).

Below function seems to be the answer for UIKit:

```
override func preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures() -> UIRectEdge {
    return [.bottom]
}
```

How can I use this function and disable iOS Reachability Swipe Gesture in SwiftUI?

Comment: Are you using the UIKit or SwiftUI lifecycle?

Comment: I am using the SwiftUI lifecycle.

Comment: Hm. That may be rough. My suspicion is that you'll have to subclass `UIHostingController` to override that property, which I guess you *could* do inside another `UIViewControllerRepresentable`, but that's much uglier than just doing it at the root level in your `SceneDelegate`

Comment: How to disable (UIKit) ONLY swipe-down (bottom) reachability gesture?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61221343/12299030 with native SwiftUI modifier added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299030/asperi) Mentioned. SwiftUI have answer for this in iOS 16+.

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyhstack/deferssystemgestures(on:))

in my case I just add

```
.defersSystemGestures(on: bottom)
```